# Запрос на подсчет з/п сотрудников

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Суть задачи: есть таблица Работников, где хранится оклад каждого сотрудника

Есть таблица Дополнительных заданий, где хранится оплата за выполнение задания.

И есть связующая таблица, где хранится id сотрудника и id работы

Мне нужно подсчитать з/п сотрудников за месяц. Проблема в том, что если человек принял участие в нескольких работах за месяц, то вычисления с ним производятся отдельно (то есть считается з/п для первой доп. работы и для второй, а не совместно).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

[image: Таблица работников][image: Таблица доп. работ][image: связующая таблица][image: процедура подсчета][image: вывод]

Comment: Думаю, стоит сначала посчитать сумму всех выполненных работ у работника, после чего сложить её с окладом. Скорее всего, понадобится подзапрос, в котором и вернём сумму выполненных работ

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st, можете подсказать, пожалуйста, как это технически реализовать? Нужно создать отдельную процедуру, которая будет считать сумму выполненных работ?

Comment: А зачем у вас payment в group by если вы берете по нему sum ? Вернее вы в одной колонке берете sum, а в лругой не берете. вы уж определитесь вам нужна в колонке полная сумма и тогда его надо убрать из group by и делать sum, и тогда будет как вы написали в условиях или все таки отдельная, но тогда понятно и строки отдельные

Comment: @Mike, если убрать payment из group by, то происходит следующая ошибка: Столбец "TypeWork.Payment" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в агрегатной функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY.

Comment: правильно пишет, вы же почему то его без sum() используете, при том что в условиях пишите что хотите видеть сумму нескольких работ

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 0):

Мог где-то опечататься, но смысл такой: в подзапросе находим сумму за все доп. работы и джоиним с окладной частью.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_TOTAL_SALARY
    @LAST_DAY smalldatetime
AS
    SELECT  W.ID_WORKER     AS "ID работника"
            W.FIRST_NAME    AS "Имя",
            W.SECOND_NAME   AS "Фамилия",
            W.SALARY        AS "Оклад",
            SP.SUM_PAYMENT  AS "Премия",
            W.SALARY + SP.SUM_PAYMENT AS "Итого"
    FROM Worker AS W
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT  ID_WORKER
                ,SUM(Payment) AS SUM_PAYMENT
        FROM ExtraWork AS EW
        JOIN TypeWork AS TW ON EW.FK_TypeWork = TW.ID_TypeWork
        WHERE YEAR(EW.LAST_DAY) = YEAR(@LAST_DAY)
            AND MONTH(EW.LAST_DAY) = MONTH(@LAST_DAY)
        GROUP BY ID_WORKER
    ) AS SP ON W.ID_WORKER = SP.ID_WORKER
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @NanReven можешь тогда отметить ответ как принятый?)